# DRF: make a POST query without data

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

cannot manage a **POST** method-query to url **/users/{pk}/subscribe**

Accesing this url should insert a record in db using Subscription model. **No data is passed in body when accessing this url**

**model.Subscription**

```
class Subscription(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User,
                             on_delete=models.CASCADE,
                             related_name='subscriber',
                             )
    author = models.ForeignKey(User,
                               on_delete=models.CASCADE,
                               related_name='subscribing'
                               )
```

a router to **users**

```
router.register(r'users', CustomUserViewSet, basename='users')
```

and the additional URL that accepts POST query in the **CustomUserViewSet**

```
class CustomUserViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = User.objects.all()
    serializer_class = CreateUserSerializer
    @action(
        detail=True,
        methods=['post', 'delete'],
        permission_classes=[IsAuthenticated],
    )
    def subscribe(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        user = request.user
        author_pk = int(kwargs.get('pk'))
        author_to_subscribe = get_object_or_404(User, id=author_pk)
        if request.method == 'DELETE':
            return Response(status=status.HTTP_204_NO_CONTENT)

        if user.pk == author_pk:
            data = {
                "errors": "Cannot subscribe to yourself"
            }
            return Response(status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST,
                            data=data)
        # q = Subscription.objects.filter(user=user)
        serializer = SubscriptionCreateSerializer(data=request.data)
        serializer.is_valid()
        serializer.save(user=user, author=author_to_subscribe)
        return Response(
                status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

Method shoould return serialized data from another serializer (SubscriptionSerializer. So i have 2 serializer for subscription: for viewing and creating

At this point in Postman getting error
[image]

```
class SubscriptionCreateSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    
    class Meta:
        model = Subscription
        fields =  '__all__'
    
    def create(self, validated_data):
        pass

class SubscriptionSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    
    email = serializers.EmailField(source='author.email')
    id = serializers.IntegerField(source='author.id')
    username = serializers.CharField(source='author.username')
    first_name = serializers.CharField(source='author.first_name')
    last_name = serializers.CharField(source='author.last_name')
    is_subscribed = serializers.BooleanField(default=True)
    recipes = serializers.SerializerMethodField()
    
    def get_recipes(self, obj):
        qs = obj.author.recipes.all()
        return RecipePublicSerializer(qs, many=True).data
    
    def to_representation(self, instance):
        representation = super().to_representation(instance)
        representation['recipes_count'] = instance.author.recipes.count()

        return representation
    
    def to_internal_value(self, data):
        recipes_data = data['recipes']

        return super().to_internal_value(recipes_data)
    
    class Meta:
        model = Subscription
        fields = ('email',
                  'id',
                  'username',
                  'first_name',
                  'last_name',
                  'is_subscribed',
                  'recipes',)


class CreateUserSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    """Serializer for creating user objects"""
    
    username = serializers.CharField(
        validators=[
            UniqueValidator(queryset=User.objects.all())
        ]
    )
    email = serializers.EmailField(
        validators=[
            UniqueValidator(queryset=User.objects.all())
        ]
    )
    first_name = serializers.CharField()
    last_name = serializers.CharField()
    password = serializers.CharField()
    is_subscribed = serializers.SerializerMethodField()
    
    @classmethod
    def get_is_subscribed(self, object):
        return True

    def validate_username(self, value):
        if value.lower() == "me":
            raise serializers.ValidationError("Username 'me' is not valid")
        return value

    def create(self, validate_data):
        user = User(**validate_data)
        user.set_password(validate_data['password'])
        user.save()
        return user

    class Meta:
        fields = ('username',
                  'email',
                  'first_name',
                  'last_name',
                  'id',
                  'is_subscribed',)
        read_only_fields = ('id',)
        model = User
```

Comment: on what line does the code breaks? And can you post the CreateUserSerializer class as well

Comment: use `serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)` to get errors of your data

Comment: line that breaks process
serializer.save(user=user, author=author_to_subscribe)

Comment: added 2 serializers

Comment: after adding raise_exceptions=True, got that user and author are required.
user - attribute from Subscription model
author = attribute from Subscription model

Comment: added to SubscriptionCreateSerializer and worked
user = UserSerializer(required=False)
author = UserSerializer(required=False)

Comment: You serializer won't create actual records in database if you overwrite create method with function which does nothing and didn't pass any parameters to it.

Answer (score 1):

As I understood from question you would like to get user from request and id of author to subscribe from url. You pass to serializer empty body of your post request, but according to your serializer you should pass  user and author fields, so to get serializer works you need to pass this parameters as data to serializer instance.

```
subscription_data = {
    'user': request.user,
    'author': author_to_subscribe
}
serializer = SubscriptionCreateSerializer(data=subscription_data)
serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
serializer.save()
```

And also remove def save() method from your SubscriptionCreateSerializer it overwrites method which should put info about subscription in DB, so in your case it does nothing instead.